# Pc won't boot after changing KernelBase.dll?

Tags: windows, assembly, kernel, kernel32

I changed the IsDebuggerPresent() function of the KernelBase.dll

from

```
00007FFF0631DE90 | mov rax,qword ptr gs:[60]               |
00007FFF0631DE99 | movzx eax,byte ptr ds:[rax+2]           |
00007FFF0631DE9D | ret                                     |
00007FFF0631DE9E | int3                                    |
00007FFF0631DE9F | int3                                    |
00007FFF0631DEA0 | int3                                    |
```

to

```
00007FFF0631DE90 | mov rax,qword ptr gs:[60]               |
00007FFF0631DE99 | mov eax,0                               |
00007FFF0631DE9E | ret                                     |
00007FFF0631DE9F | int3                                    |
00007FFF0631DEA0 | int3                                    |
```

so that the function always returns zero, which means that no user mode debugger is present.(afaik)

Now when i overwrite the original KernelBase.dll in the System32-Folder and i reboot my pc i get a bluescreen while booting and then i have to "restore to a point where the pc booted well".

So my questions are:

Why can't windows boot properly after such a small change?

What's the matter and how may i fix it?

Comment: for example because this critical windows image is **signed** and even one bit changed  - broke signature. system detect this and not boot. you even not post bsod code. anyway patch system images not solution for `IsDebuggerPresent`

Comment: *how may i fix it?* - very simply  - not patch system files. this is not solution

Comment: Solution: use plugins for debuggers to avoid debugger detection. Which plugins to use is depend on u

Comment: *"Doctor, it hurts when I do this."* ...

Comment: @RbMm thanks man, that answered my questions